# How to automatically submit button once form load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating one simple demo for automatic login.
Scenario is that i have default username and password.
In that i have to create javascript or jquery which can find the iframe and automatic click on submit button once page load and directly redirect on form action page.
[image]

Here is image attached in that index page have loaded iframe and other login page.
So i have to find username and password textbox and pass the default values in that and automatically submit button. All should be going through javascript or jquery.

Thanks

Comment: i have tried to get id of iframe and textbox using jquery but not getting proper result.

Comment: I will be good, if you improve your question by adding the code which you have tried.

Comment: I have tried jquery code on console that $("#iframeID").contents().find("#myDiv");  so i can find hierarchically iframe -> inside that div -> and textbox in that div

Comment: What's the purpose of this kind of behavior? Having default user name and the password on client side in javascript, than there is no reason for having login, everybody can see the default login and password.

Comment: Even so, is the page loaded in the iframe on the same domain as the page that contains the iframe? If not, you will not be able to access the DOM object of the iframe using javascript.

Comment: Understand that We have same Gmail login page on our site. what we have to do that when our page loaded before we have to login and display Gmail account in our site..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#username').val('default_username'); //Find and set default username
   $('#password').val('default_password'); //Find and set default password

   //Submit the form using jQuery
   $("form").submit();
});
```

You can also submit the form using id of Form like `$("#formId").submit();`

Comment: Mathew above code will work as per your requirement. It will automatically submit the form once page loaded.

Comment: Hey Mathew, just need jquery to be included. See this https://jsfiddle.net/8x2bxk73/3/